# pushing a nested array in a form control in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a form of this structure in angular

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      description: ["", Validators.required],
      item: this._fb.array([
     ])
});
```

I am using this functions to patch the form values

```
patchFormArray(item: any) {
   let ctrl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.item;
    item.forEach(items => {
       const fb = this._fb.group({
         prefix:  [items?items.prefix:"", Validators.required],
         text: [items?items.text:"", Validators.required],
         Questiontype: [items?items.Questiontype:"", Validators.required],
         options: this._fb.array([ ])
       })
        fb.patchValue(item);
        ctrl.push(fb);
      })
   }

   patchFormData(data: any){
      this.myForm.patchValue({
         name: data.name,
         description: data.description
      })
   }
```

I want to patch the values of options array which is in the item array. I have tried with this function but it is still not working. Added InitOptionArray function yet still not working

```
patchOptionsArray(items:any){
  var index = 0
     items.forEach(item => {
       let Optionsctrl = <FormArray>this.myForm.get(['item', index, 'options']);
          items[index].options.forEach(option => {
               Optionsctrl.push(
                 this._fb.group({
                   value:  [option?option.value:""]
                 })
               )
          });
         index = index + 1;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managing formArray inside a reactive form  in angular can be complicated. I created my on pattern to develop and keep my code as clean as possible, I m going to tell you how I manage my reactive forms with formArrays inside

let say you have a formGroup that holds a formArray inside

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        name: this._fb.control("",[Validators.required]),
        description: this._fb.control("",[Validators.required]),
        item: this._fb.array([])
  });
```

notice I leave my formArray declaration empty because I m going to used a method to manage the formGroups inside

I m going to create a method that return my item Array from the formGroup, this method will everywhere

```
get items(): FormArray {
  return this.myForm.get("items") as FormArray
}
```

Now: how to declare a form group inside the formArray? , this method will accept values like a optional parameter values I m going to set up

```
addItem(values?: any) {
  const tempFormGroup = this._fb.group({
    prefix: this._fb.control("",[Validators.required]),
    options:this._fb.array([]), //adding the array field
  })

 if(values) {
  tempFormGroup.setValue(values)
 }
 this.items.push(tempFormGroup)
}
```

How you delete a formGroup inside your form array? you will need the index of the specific formGroup that you want to delete

```
removeItem(index:number ) {
   this.items.removeAt(index)
 }
```

If you have another formArray inside your internal formControl you will need to handled it in the same way as his parent

**UDATED**

if you have another array inside the first array you will need to know both index to be able to manage the sencond array

```
options(index:number):  FormArray {
  return this.items.at(index).get("options") as FormArray
}

addOptions(itemIndex:number, values?:any) {
  this.options(index).push(this._fb.group({...}))
}

removeOptions(itemIndex:number,optionIndex:number){
  this.options(itemIndex).removeAt(index)
}
```

let me know if you need more help

greetings

Comment: please I updated the question. I still don't know how to go about this

Comment: What exactly you don’t know? How to access to the form array inside your form array?

Comment: Yeah exactly when I have an array inside another array

Comment: @UnahHenry check my answer again and see if that help you

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation was really helpful but I solved the problem using the patchOptionsArray() and patchFormArray().